# How to writer signature of function pointer that returns impl Future?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to design a function `send_with_retry` that sends a message and then tries again if the connection closes. The errors and results are not placed here to make it very simple, but in the real example it'd watch for the returned values so it knows when the connection closes or succeeds.

```
struct Client {
    
}

impl Client {
    async fn send_and_expect(
        &mut self
    ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn connection_retrier(
        f: fn(&mut Self) -> std::result::Result<(), ()>,
        f_self: &mut Self,
    ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    
    fn send_with_retry(&mut self) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
           Client::connection_retrier(Client::send_and_expect, &mut self)
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error:
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:20:39
   |
20 |            Client::connection_retrier(Client::send_and_expect, &mut self)
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Client) -> std::result::Result<(), ()>`
                 found fn item `for<'_> fn(&mut Client) -> impl Future {Client::send_and_expect}`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The problem is, of course, because I specified a function poiter `f` that returns a `Result`, but I pass a pointer to an `async` function, which desugar to a function that returns an `impl Future`.

What would be the correct function signature to put in the `f` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `send_and_expect` method is an async function, it returns a `Future` with output `Result<(), ()>`. Also, since this async function accepts the `&mut self` parameter, the future's lifetime is also bound to the same.

So, you can define a generic type parameter which implements the Future trait that outputs `Result<(), ()>` with same lifetime as of the `&mut Self` parameter of `fn` pointer.

```rust
use std::future::Future;

impl Client {
    async fn send_and_expect(
        &mut self
    ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn connection_retrier<'a, T>(
        f: fn(&'a mut Self) -> T,
        f_self: &mut Self,
    ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> 
    where
        T: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ()>> + 'a
    {
        Ok(())
    }
    
    fn send_with_retry(&mut self) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
           Client::connection_retrier(Client::send_and_expect, &mut *self)
    }
}
```

Comment: How an I match the result of `f` inside `connection_retrier`? I tried `match f(f_self, request, unauthorized_retry) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),` but I get `expected type parameter `T`, found enum `std::result::Result`
`